# but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebApplication4.Models.modelExemplo]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc

Não consigo realizar enumerar, já troquei para outra recepção de informação na View mas não sei como corrigir, verifiquei outras formas no StackOverflow mas não compreendi.

**Model:**

```
namespace WebApplication4.Models
{
    public class modelExemplo
    {
        public StringBuilder lista { get; set; } = new StringBuilder();

    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
namespace WebApplication4.Controllers{

    public ActionResult funcaodeteste()
    {               
        modelExemplo obj = new modelExemplo();
        obj.listNewsletter.AppendLine("teste1");
        obj.listNewsletter.AppendLine("teste2");

        return View(obj);       
    }

}
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication4.Models.modelExemplo>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Download</title>
</head>
<body>



    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <p>item</p>
    }


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Porque você declarou o Stringbuilder dentro do seu construtor ?

Comment: Porque é necessário eu instanciar o objeto StringBuilder para poder utiliza-lo pois se eu tentar inserir e não tiver instanciado ele dará NullReference

Comment: Instanciar sim, mas não defini-lo dentro do mesmo...

Comment: @Matheus, existe uma outra forma pois desconheço, aquilo não está dentro de um construtor é uma instância no atributo, eu poderia fazer desta forma também:
public StringBuilder lista { get; set; }
public modelExemplo(){
lista = new StringBuilder;
}

Comment: Erro meu... Desconsidere

Comment: @Matheus sem problem, rs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua view está tipada para um `IEnumerable<WebApplication4.Models.modelExemplo>`, ou seja, vários `modelExemplo` e no seu return você envia somente um. Altere na sua view para `@model WebApplication4.Models.modelExemplo` que funcionará. Se precisar de uma lista, instancie uma lista no seu controller e retorne ela;

Para retornar a lista (obs.: mantenha o `IEnumerable` no `@model`):

```
IEnumerable<modelExemplo> lista = new List<modelExemplo>();
modelExemplo obj = new modelExemplo();
obj.listNewsletter.AppendLine("teste1");
obj.listNewsletter.AppendLine("teste2");
lista.Add(obj)  
return View(lista);
```

Comment: Isto faz apresentar isto:
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'WebApplication4.Models.modelExemplo' because 'WebApplication4.Models.modelExemplo' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Se você enviar somente 1 cara ao invés da lista que estava enviando, não vai conseguir usar foreach, correto? rs Foreach se usa em lista e não em 1 objeto apenas, e o seu "Model" ali, representa o "@using" que deixou de ser uma lista. Pra usar a lista, faz do jeito que ta ali em cima

Comment: Porque crias um stringbuilder? quando o que me parece que queres criar é uma lista de strings?!

Comment: Eu não criei stringbuilder, foi o @rock.ownar.

Answer (score 0):

Como disse antes, penso que o que queres fazer é passar uma lista de strings não? dentro do teu objecto model, crias a lista e depois percorres a dita lista..

Agora uma nota: caso o teu objectivo seja simplesmente passar essa lista e nada mais para a view, nem precisas criar um model para isso, poderias simplemente criar a lista no controller e enviar a lista, ai no using da view definias apenas o objecto List e no foreach usavas simplesmente o Model ao inves do Model.lista

MODEL

```
 namespace WebApplication4.Models
{
    public class modelExemplo
    {
        public List<string> lista { get; set; };

    }
}
```

CONTRLLER:

```
namespace WebApplication4.Controllers{

    public ActionResult funcaodeteste()
    {               
        modelExemplo obj = new modelExemplo();
        obj.lista = new List<string>();

         obj.lista.Add("teste1");
        obj.lista.Add("teste2");

        return View(obj);       
    }

}
```

VIEW

```
@model WebApplication4.Models.modelExemplo

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Download</title>
</head>
<body>



    @foreach (var item in Model.lista) {
        <p>item</p>
    }


</body>
</html>
```